# How to disable OK button in QInputDialog if nothing is typed?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to disable the OK button until the user types something in the text field but I was unable to do it so far... Following is the excerpt of my code where the OK button is active from the beginning.

```
    inputDialog=QInputDialog()
    text, ok = inputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog','Enter name')

    print ("text,ok",text,ok)
    if ok:
        return (text.upper(), ok)
    else: 
        return ('',ok)
```

Comment: It's not possible to do this without sub-classing `QInputDialog`. You might as well just write your own dialog that does exactly what you want. It's only a line-edit and a couple of buttons.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment answers the question. It is not possible with QInputDialog. Alternatively, write a custom QLineEdit obj with two buttons.